# Unable to figure how to manage foreign keys for 'project-customers-contacts' relation

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a `CUSTOMERS` table and a `CONTACTS` table the relation between them is one to many obviously.
also I have `PROJECTS` table and `PROJECT_CUSTOMERS` table with relation one to many and with relation one to one between `CUSTOMERS` and `PROJECT_CUSTOMERS`.
my problem is that I have a fifth table `PROJECT_CONTACTS` ....I can't figure which tables shall I refer to in this tables, currently I am refering to `PROJECT_CUSTOMERS` and `CONTACTS` table, is this correct or there is something better ?

Comment: "Obviously one to many"? Two customers can't have the same contact? Ditto for projects. (With consequences for "one to one").

Comment: Two customers can't have the same contact

Comment: Could you further explain the problem / context / situation here? As @philipxy said, for us it is not obvious something of your problem, we do not know the real context here. To simply put, could you explain the reason for the existence of these relationships between these tables? With this, I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your title refers to "foreign keys" but your question just seems to be about what columns should go in what tables.

First, decide what situations can arise and what you want/need to say about them. (This will your tables, columns, candidate keys, foreign keys and constraints.)

Every table holds rows that make some predicate (statement template parameterized by column names) true. Your design seems to have:

```
CUSTOMERS(id, ...) -- ID identifies a customer and ...
CONTACTS(id, ...) -- ID identifies a contact and ...
PROJECTS(id, ...) -- ID identifies a project and ...
PROJECT_CUSTOMERS(pid, cust_id, ...) -- project PID has customer CUST_ID and ...
PROJECT_CONTACTS(pid, cont_id, cust_id)...)
    -- project PID has contact CONT_ID and project pid has customer CUST_ID and ...
```

A foreign key has a table & column list referencing a table and column list that forms a candidate key. It says that lists of values in the first table appear as lists of values in the second table. Where that is so, declare a foreign key.

Comment: I have edited my answer slightly. 1. I have *guessed* the comments above (which determine the tables and columns) about what you want to say about situations. *You* need to tell *us* what they really are.  2. What is the first thing that you don't understand?

Comment: nice, now my question is :
should PROJECT_CONTACTS.cust_id refer to PROJECT_CUSTOMERS.cust_id or to CUSTOMERS.id ? ..... also should PROJECT_CONTACTS.pid refer to PROJECT_CUSTOMERS.pid or to PROJECTS.id ......note that CONTACTS is actually CONTACTS(id,cust_id,.....) where cust_id refers to CUSTOMER.id

Comment: "[A FK] says that lists of values in the first table appear as lists of values in the second table. Where that is so, declare a foreign key." So re PROJECT_CONTACTS: If `project PID has contact CONT_ID and project PID has customer CUST_ID and ...`, will it also true that `CUST_ID identifies a customer and ...` for some `...` parameters? Ie that if `CONT_ID` appears in one table it appears in the other? And will it also be true that `project PID has contact CONT_ID and project PID has customer CUST_ID and ...` for some `CONT_ID` & `...` parameters? PS Again: please give the *correct* comments.

Comment: Re "where cust_id refers to CUSTOMER.id": Do you mean that there's a FK `CONTACTS (cust_id) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (id)`? If so, *why* are is there? Otherwise, what does "refers to" *mean*? When you are talking about the meanings of tables, ie which rows go into them, it is not helpful to say the vague "refers to" but it is helpful to give each table's *predicate*. (And see my last comment.)